# Windows 10 failed during update. All fixes I've attempted have failed

Tags: windows-10, boot, data-recovery, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

Yes I should of made a backup, that was very bad of me.

Last night I was attempting to update my PC. The option I clicked was "Restart and Update" (Not exact wording). There was no "Update and Shutdown" option. The update was proceeding normally. There was a message saying it would restart several times during the update. On the first restart I get the message:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected
> Boot device and press a key

Pressing a key does nothing but bring up the message again.

I created a Windows 10 Install Device on a USB flash drive. I'm able to boot into that. Here are the following things I have tried:

- Under "Repair Your computer" > Troubleshoot > Advance options

  - **Startup Repair** - Fails and prints "Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC"
  - **System Restore** - None available
  - **System Image Recovery** - None available
  - **Uninstall latest quality update** - Message saying "We ran into a problem and won't be able to uninstall the latest quality update of Windows."
  - **Uninstall latest feature update** - Message saying "We ran into a problem and won't be able to uninstall the latest feature update of Windows."
- Under "Repair Your Computer" > Troubleshoot > Command Prompt

  - Ran `bootrec /scanos` - Finds 2 installations. `[1] C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS` and `[2] C:\Windows`
  - Ran `bootrec /rebuildbcd` - Found `C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS` and `C:\Windows` and prints the error "The requested system device cannot be found".
  - Ran `bootrec /fixmbr` - Runs. Prints "The operation completed successfully."
  - Ran `bootrec /fixboot` - Fails. Prints "Access is denied."

I then attempted the method described here https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied-error-on-windows-10/ but that had no effect.

I then kinda gave up and attempted to reinstall Windows 10:

- Select "Windows 10 Home"
- Select "Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)
- See the following:

  - Drive 0 Partition 1: Recovery (450.0 MB) Type: Recovery
  - Drive 0 Partition 2 (830.0 MB) Type: Recovery
  - Drive 0 Partition 3 (99.0 MB) Type: System
  - Drive 0 Partition 4 (930.2 GB) Type: Primary
- I'm unable to instal Widows from here. The error at the bottom says "Windows can't be installed on drive 0 partition **#**. (Show details)

  - The error if I select partition 4 reads: "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style."

Questions:

- Is there **any** way to recover from this without formatting my drive?
- What is the best way to recover my data from my drive before I reinstall from scratch if that is what I have to do?
- What could of caused such a horrible failure?

**Edit 1:** This is a custom build Desktop PC. Main drive is a Samsung M.2 SSD.

Comment: Why does Windows do this? Something happened to hopelessly corrupt the operating system and environment. I have seen this several time.  In all of the cases I have seen, formatting the drive (assuming the drive to be physically good) is the only way out. That has been my experience.

Comment: Pull the drive and connect to another PC using a sata to usb adapter, copy your data off, put it back in the original PC and re-install W10.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting into automatic restore maybe it might take you back to restore point, by removing your battery and charger then hold down the power button for 3 minutes,then plugged back your battery and charger,but if does not go back am sorry their is no way you can restore your data you will have to format your system when you get to this place

Drive 0 Partition 1: Recovery (450.0 MB) Type: Recovery
Drive 0 Partition 2 (830.0 MB) Type: Recovery
Drive 0 Partition 3 (99.0 MB) Type: System
Drive 0 Partition 4 (930.2 GB) Type: Primary

You delete everything then you load on empty space,then happy seeing your new windows

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a desktop computer? I assume this method would work by unplugging the main power.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Cause of horrible failure**

Since you did say by USB flash drive while making bootable USB you must have selected MBR but your partitions have are in GPT style so this caused this horrific damage

**2.Fixes**

You should try to make the USB bootable by making GPT mode and try to reinstall windows without formatting the drive to install windows without losing data

[image]

If still installation fails Without formatting drive You may have to go to then data recovery specialists who do recover data  so you need to contact them

Note:Do not in any case format the drive because you will reduce chances of data recovery to great extent